# Unable to open the directory when deleted the read all access & added the read-write access in configuration file of Subversion

Tags: apache, svn, subversion-edge

I have installed SVN in my linux box and I am using version 1.6.11 (r934486) of SVN and I am facing some problem with the configuration.

I have created one repository named as KH and earlier i have given the read all access in auth file - like this

```
[groups]
support_rw = ranjeet, rahul, monika, devesh

[KH:/]

* = r
@support_rw = rw
```

and now I wanted to remove everyone to read this directory so i did this:

```
[KH:/]

* = 

@support_rw = rw
```

And after this i am not able to login into my directory.

I have read some articles about it. I have also checked my `subversion.conf` file in subversion and it is like this only:

```
<IfModule !dav_svn_module>
LoadModule dav_svn_module     modules/mod_dav_svn.so
<IfModule !dav_svn_module>
    LoadModule dav_svn_module     modules/mod_dav_svn.so
</IfModule>
<IfModule !authz_svn_module>
    LoadModule authz_svn_module   modules/mod_authz_svn.so
 </IfModule>


<Location /svn/KH>
DAV svn
SVNParentPath /var/www/svnRepos/KH

# Limit write permission to list of valid users.
<LimitExcept GET PROPFIND OPTIONS REPORT>
  # Require SSL connection for password protection.
  # SSLRequireSSL

  AuthType Basic
  AuthName "Authorization Realm for KH repository"
  AuthUserFile /etc/httpd/svn-conf.d/svn-auth-conf-KH
  AuthzSVNAccessFile /etc/httpd/svn-conf.d/svn-acl-conf-KH
  Require valid-user
  </LimitExcept>
 </Location>
```

I am getting following error:

> server sent unexpected return value (403 Forbidden)

Comment: Can you try:   
`[groups]`  
`support_rw = ranjeet, rahul, monika, devesh`  

`[/]`  
`@support_rw = rw`

Comment: @triadiktyo ...as suggested by you i have tried but it is not working for me

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have find out how to accomplish this.

If we have to make the anonymous reader to read the repository. We have to put the LimitExcept tag in the subversion(repository-conf-file).conf file.

> Here in above question we have to make sure that anonymous reader is not even able to read the repository so just delete the LimitExcept tag in the subversion.conf file.

It solved my problem and it is running perfectly fine for me